# Can't call Javascript function twice

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function to slowly move an image around the screen. The relevant html is as follows:

```js
var dom, timer;

    function initImage() {
        dom = document.getElementById('animate').style;
        dom.position = 'absolute';
        dom.top = "165px";
        dom.left = "767px";
        regulate(1115,165);
        regulate(1115,540);
        regulate(767,540);
        regulate(767, 165);
    }
    
    function regulate(xfinal, yfinal) {
        var timer = setInterval(function() {moveImage(xfinal,yfinal)}, 1);
        return true;
    }

    function moveImage(xfinal, yfinal) {
        var x = parseInt(dom.left.match(/\d+/));
        var y = parseInt(dom.top.match(/\d+/));
        
        if ((x == xfinal) && (y== yfinal)) {clearInterval(timer);}
        else {
            if (x != xfinal) {
                if (x < xfinal) {x++;}
                else {x--;};
                dom.left = x + "px";}
            else {
                if (y < yfinal) {y++;}
                else {y--;};
                dom.top = y + "px";};
            };
        return true;
    }
```

```html
<img src='http://placehold.it/200' alt='Sir Victor' width=50 height=50
     id='animate' onload='initImage();' style='position:absolute;'/>
```

This algorithm works fine for the first function call to regulate(), but when I uncomment one of the other three and try to run it, the image either doesn't move at all, or it moves faster than normal, but only along the first path. Is there some reason the function won't act as expected the second time?

I'm new to javascript, so feel free to point out anything else that seems dumb or over-complicated as well.

Comment: can you provide this code in plunkr ?

Comment: You need to place `timer` within the global scope as well (given you're referencing it in both `moveImage` and `regulate`. (May not be THE issue, but it's at least AN issue.

Comment: you are passing timer variable before it is assigned a value!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling all the `regulate` functions at once; set up a queue.

```js
var dom;
var timer;
var queueIndex = 0;
var positions = [
    [300, 0],
    [300, 100],
    [0, 100],
    [0, 0]
];

function initImage() {
    dom = document.getElementById('animate').style;
    dom.position = 'absolute';
    dom.top = "0px";
    dom.left = "0px";
    regulate.apply(null, positions[queueIndex]);
}

function regulate(xfinal, yfinal) {
    timer = setInterval(moveImage, 1, xfinal, yfinal);
    return true;
}

function moveImage(xfinal, yfinal) {
    var x = parseInt(/\d+/.exec(dom.left) || 0);
    var y = parseInt(/\d+/.exec(dom.top) || 0);

    if ((x == xfinal) && (y == yfinal)) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        queueIndex++;
        if (positions[queueIndex]) {
            regulate.apply(null, positions[queueIndex]);
        }
    } else {
        if (x != xfinal) {
            if (x < xfinal) {
                x++;
            } else {
                x--;
            };
            dom.left = x + "px";
        } else {
            if (y < yfinal) {
                y++;
            } else {
                y--;
            };
            dom.top = y + "px";
        };
    };
    return true;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://libcom.org/files/images/library/black-square.jpg' alt='Sir Victor' width=50 height=50 id='animate' onload='initImage();' style='position:absolute;' />
```

Comment: I made the edits you suggested, still not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that you can't pass the contents of the `timer` variable to `setInterval()` in this line:

```
 var timer = setInterval(moveImage, 1, xfinal, yfinal, timer);
```

because the value of `timer` is not available until after `setInterval()` returns.

Thus, you will just be passing `undefined` for that value so your `clearInterval()` in `moveImage()` will not work properly.

The usual way to solve this problem is to declare the `timer` variable in some higher level shared scope so it will be available as needed.